# setting typename default value for vardiac and normal template

Tags: c++, c++11

```
template<typename T, T... Xs> class Nzm
{
private:
template<typename... Ts> static constexpr T Max(Ts... xs);

template<typename Tx> static constexpr T Max(Tx x)
{
    return x;
}

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename... Ts> static constexpr T Max(T1 x, T2 y, Ts... xs)
{
    return y > x ? Max<T2, Ts...>(y, xs...) : Max<T1, Ts...>(x, xs...);
}

public:
static const T Z = Max(Xs...);
};


int main() {

static_assert(Nzm<int,1,2,3,4,5,6>::Z==5,"XYZ");

return 0;
}
```

I already know that all the typename are going to be int and I only want to use

```
Nzm<1,2,3,4,5,6>
```

instead of

```
Nzm<int,1,2,3,4,5,6>
```

this is for compile time execution no code or tips for making it runtime.
is this possible? to set all this typename to int ?

Comment: Why would the maximum of 1,2,3,4,5,6 be 5?

Comment: Are you saying that `T` is always `int` *in this case* or is `T` *always* `int`?

Comment: that's a point to print XYZ just testing

Comment: `template<int... Is> class Nzm` Doesn't work for you?

Comment: yup T is always int

Comment: [It works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22dba3d584bdbb0e) just change your static_assert to be correct.

Comment: storyTeller will it work in compile time?

Comment: If `T` is always `int`, then why template in the first place?

Comment: my issue is I dont want to put that int typename as i mention

Comment: @VenuKantSahu - Of course. Are you familiar with non-type template parameters? You can have packs of those as well

Comment: i used template to calculate Max in compile time

Comment: @StoryTeller not that much clear i can read that stuff. but is it possible to make all int with that?

Comment: Yes. You can have a template that accepts an unspecified number of integers. A parameter pack of non-type parameters...

Comment: @StoryTeller, why don't you make it a proper answer?

Comment: I'm new user first of all, I'm learning things here only, what do you mean with a proper answer?

Comment: @SergeyA - Just Did. Wanted to be sure that's what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick solution is to use a `using` declaration to get ride of the int.

```
template<int... x>
using helper =  Nzm<int, x...>;

int main() {

    static_assert(helper<1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6>::Z == 6, "XYZ");

    return 0;
}
```

Another (better) way is to modify Nzm and replace all the `typename` templates with `int` templates. You're left with a redundancy between the parameters and template arguments, so you can get rid of the parameters.

```
template<int... Xs> class Nzm
{
private:
    template<int x> static constexpr int Max()
    {
        return x;
    }

    template<int x, int y, int... rest> static constexpr int Max()
    {
        return x > y ? Max<x, rest...>() : Max<y, rest...>();
    }

public:
    static const int Z = Max<Xs...>();
};

int main() {

    static_assert(Nzm<1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6>::Z == 6, "XYZ");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: assertion failed at Z==6 try that

Comment: @VenuKantSahu Yep, that will make the assertion pass. I left it as is because it was not part of the question. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @VenuKantSahu: I've said it before and I'll say it again... your static_assert is wrong! Your are hoping the maximum is 5, when in reality it's 6

Comment: but fpr Z==6 it has to print nothing but it prints you can check assertion also failed for Z==6

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thanks helper is working for me but can I rename it?

Comment: @VenuKantSahu yes, you can use whatever name you want, helper is just an example. However, the first solution is helpful if you are not able to edit the class you are using. If you can edit `Nzm` then I recommend you use the second solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a template that accepts a parameter pack of `int`s, have yourself such a template:

```
template<int ...Is> class Nzm {
  // Your implementation follows
};
```

Templates can accept parameters which aren't types (among them parameters which are integers), and consequently they can accept analogous parameter packs.

Comment: You are right but my main issue is to run this at compile time only.

Comment: It __is__ at compile time!